# Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been using the code,

```
  object amountObject = MySqlDAL.ExecuteQuerySingle(query);

        if (amountObject.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
        {
            return amount;
        }
```

here in some point am getting an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." from the sentence amountObject.Equals(System.DBNull.Value). Its working fine for some set of data.

What may be the reason? Can any one please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the result for null as well..

```
if (amountObject ==null || amountObject.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))          
{             
     return amount;         
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, myself. It will work, but ExecuteQuerySingle should have **one** documented way of returning a null result... and that one way is what the client code should check for.

Comment: @Jon agreed, would be better taking a look inside `ExecuteQuerySingle` and fixing the problem at source.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. Let me check.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `MySqlDAL.ExecuteQuerySingle` is returning `null` instead of `System.DBNull.Value`. It's hard to know whether that's a bug in your expectations or in `ExecuteQuerySingle` though.

Comment: Yes Mr Jon  its returning null value. So it cannot be checked in that way? It is  that same as System.DBNull.Value right?

Comment: @Anjana: No, `DBNull.Value` is a non-null reference *representing* a null result from a database, but it's not the same as a null reference. You need to find out whether the method is meant to return a null reference or `DBNull.Value`, and act accordingly.

Comment: Mr jon. Now its working as i changed the checking criteria as         ok if (amountObject ==null || amountObject.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))          
{             
     return amount;         
}  Thanks for the info

Comment: @Anjana: While that will work, you shouldn't have to do that. Find out what it's *meant* to return, and only test for that.

Comment: @ Mr Jon actually the same piece of code has been used for two different scenarios.

Comment: @Anjana: That sounds like a bad idea to me. You might want to consider an adapter which can give you results in a consistent form. You really *don't* want to be dealing with two different values for the same logical outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the query doesn't return a value, therefore `amountObject` is null.

Manually run the query with the parameters that make this fail, there's something wrong with your SQL.

Comment: Yes.  The problem was with the checking criteria. Now its worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just change:
    if (amountObject.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
        {
            return amount;
        }

to:
    if (amountObject != null && amountObject.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
        {
            return amount;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if amountObject is null? It seems that the returned value by `MySqlDAL.ExecuteQuerySingle` return NULL.

Comment: Yes Mr Falcon its returning null value.